Prove that the sequence defined by recurrence is periodic
Been stuck here for a while, can anybody help me? Thanks!
Prove that the sequence defined recursively such that $$a_{n+1} = \frac{2}{2-a_n}$$ is periodic and has a period p = 4. We know that $a_1 \neq 0$ ;

Write $a_{n+2}$ as function of $a_n$.

Thank you! I think you meant to write $a_{n+4}$ as a function of $a_n$. It worked out in the end. Now i can say that since it's periodic, the sequence is also divergent

I think @mihaild's point is that, if $a_{n+2}=g(a_n)$, then $g(g(x))=x$. So it's a little more efficient to check the periodicity of $g$.
